# Translation commands for package dramatist to put in the marathi.ldf file

Tags: polyglossia, dramatist, translations, marathi

I want to use package dramatist to write a play in language Marathi. I am using package polyglossia in XeLaTeX for Marathi. The package dramatist prints some theatrical terms via some commands. E.g., the command `\scenename` prints  "Scene (and scene number in roman)". I want the word दृश्य to be printed instead of "Scene", and have the counter set to Devanagari script. Therefore, following the package documentation, I use `\renewcommand{\scenename}{दृश्य}` in the preamble. Similarly, I change the counter to Devanagari script.

My question is, how can I add these translation commands to the ldf (marathi.ldf) file for language Marathi in package poyloglossia so that I do not have to keep writing these commands all the time in the preamble?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is writing your commands in a new file, say `mycommands.tex`:

```
\renewcommand{\scenename}{Your scenename}
%etc.
```

and loading it using `input{mycommands}` if it is in the same folder as your .tex file. But it you really need to edit the gloss file, it is in `texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia` as `gloss-marathi.ldf` (change the year if your version of TeX Live is different; the tree structure is similar for MiKTeX). Create a backup first, say, `gloss-marathi-backup.ldf` and then add your commands to `gloss-marathi.ldf` (using `sudo` in Linux if your permission is denied or administrator privileges in Windows).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. What I really want is the command in marathi.ldf. I doubt if \renewcommand can be directly put in the .ldf file, can it be?
There are other packages also for which such translations are required. The goal is to get general trick to add the translation commands in the .ldf file, and update these translations on Git repository of polyglossia. Then they will become available to all users.

Comment: Oh, you should communicate with the maintainers of the package.

Comment: The trick I comment would only work for you computer. See the mails in the documentation files.

Comment: Yes, I could guess that the trick works locally. Will try communicative the package maintainers.